# How to exclude duplicates

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I wanna get person's birth date by name, but without duplicates.

I see here they are because of different date format: `03` and `3`.

But I don't know how to actually ignore it, tried `select distinct`, which didn't help.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select distinct ?person ?birthDate
where {
  ?person foaf:name "Julius Caesar"@en.
  ?person a foaf:Person.
  ?person dbo:birthDate ?birthDate
}
```

This is what I get:

```
    person                                                  birthDate
1   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Julius_Caesar               "-100-07-13"^^xsd:date
2   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Julius_Caesar               "-100-7-13"^^xsd:date
3   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Julius_Caesar_(cricketer)   "1830-03-25"^^xsd:date
4   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Julius_Caesar_(cricketer)   "1830-3-25"^^xsd:date
5   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Julius_Caesar_(judge)       "1557-1-1"^^xsd:date
```

when I need to have only 3 results instead of 5.

Comment: almost impossible, the problem is in the dataset which still contains the invalid date literals, i.e. `"-100-7-13"^^xsd:date` which is invalid and then they added the valid form `"-100-07-13"^^xsd:date`. You should contact the DBpedia guys and/or try DBpedia Live endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Well, those *are* `DISTINCT` result rows.

If you don't care *which* of the not-necessarily-valid dates you get, you can use `SAMPLE()`, as below, [results seen here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3Fperson%20SAMPLE%28%3FbirthDate%29%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20foaf%3Aname%20%22Julius%20Caesar%22%40en.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20a%20foaf%3APerson.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%3FbirthDate%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT DISTINCT                         ?person 
                ( SAMPLE(?birthDate) AS ?DoB )
WHERE
 {
   ?person  foaf:name      "Julius Caesar"@en .
   ?person  a              foaf:Person .
   ?person  dbo:birthDate  ?birthDate
  }
```